# How do I turn on Ancestry's Relationship Calculator?

Tags: ancestry.com

The "relationship to me" feature has disappeared from my tree on Ancestry. I rely on this heavily not to get sucked down rabbit holes of people not actually connected except by marriage.

I've deleted cookies and emptied cache. I've tried a different browser. How can I get it to re-appear?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  What program/app/website are you asking about?

Comment: I used that feature of ancestry.com.au today without a problem. What were the precise and detailed steps that you performed?

Comment: This reads as if you intended to post it to Ancestry support... We can't fix Ancestry's software.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  If you're talking about Ancestry's tree system, check under the tree settings.  The relationship calculator appears when "Who you are in this tree" and "Your home person in this tree" are set to the same person.  You can use the Edit link under your question to add information and improve your question.  If you need more information about how the site works, see the [help].

Answer (score 3):

Ancestry's Relationship Calculator was apparently introduced around 2010 and is shown in this early blog post: [Find out how you are related to other people in your Ancestry.com Member Tree](https://www.ancestry.com/corporate/blog/find-out-how-you-are-related-to-other-people-in-your-ancestry-com-member-tree) (October 7, 2010).

The support article [Seeing How People in Your Ancestry Tree are related to you](https://support.ancestry.com/s/article/Seeing-How-People-in-Your-Ancestry-Tree-are-Related-to-You?language=en_US) has partial instructions on how to activate the Relationship Calculator. To get started:

> 1. In your tree, click the tree name menu in the top-left corner and select **Tree Settings**.
> 2. On the right side of the page beneath **Who you are in this tree**, click choose. If “who you are” has already been set and you want to
>    change it, click **change**.
> 3. Start typing your name, then select it from the drop-down menu that appears.
> 4. Once you’ve chosen your name, click **Select**.

Since these articles were written, the way the Relationship Calculator works has changed, but the support article doesn't reflect this.

According to Ancestry's [Crista Cowan](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2F65E97B57EF8279) (her "Barefoot Genealogist" videos can be seen on YouTube), to make the Relationship Calculator appear, you *also* have to set yourself as the home person in the tree.

This setting is on the right side of the page, above **Who You Are in This Tree**.

Once you are set as the home person, **and** who you are in this tree, the Relationship Calculator should reappear in the banner on a person's profile.

You can use the Relationship Calculator to check the relationship betwen any two people on your tree, as long as both settings are set to the same person.  That is, if you are showing your tree to a child or cousin, set that person as the home person and "who you are", and the calculator will show the relationship to that person instead. Once you are finished, you can restore settings to yourself as "home" and "who you are" to see the relationship to you.